# Show that planar graph has at least 4 nodes of degree 5 of less

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am having a problem with this assignment. So the task says:

```
Show that every planar graph with at least 4 vertices has at least 4 
vertices of degree less than or equal to 5.
```

I know about the theorem stating that every planar graph has to have at least one vertex of degree 5 or less and that is shown by contradiction with the following inequality:

$3n-6 \ge m \ge 3n $

where $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertices,
and I guess I should prove the above statement using this, but how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider a maximally planar graph $G$ - that is, $G+e$ is not planar for any $e \not \in E(G)$. Note that proving that a maximally planar graph has at least 4 vertices of degree 5 or less is sufficient to prove that any planar graph has at least 4 vertices of degree 5 or less, since we could successively add edges to any planar graph to obtain a maximally planar graph. Now $G$ cannot have any vertices of degree 2 or less. If $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree 0 or 1, we could add an edge from that vertex to another vertex in the face containing $v$, so $G$ is not maximally planar. If $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree 2, there must be a face of length 4 or more, which you can add an edge to. So $\delta(G) \geq 3$.

Now suppose $G$ has at most 3 vertices of degree 5 or less. Then $2m \geq$ $6(n-3) + 3 \cdot 3$ $=$ $6n-9$. But since $m \leq 3n-6$, we have $2m \leq 6n-12$, a contradiction.

Comment: If G has a vertex of degree 2, there must be a face of length 4 or more? Why?

Comment: Suppose $u$ is a vertex of degree 2 with neighbors $v$ and $w$. Consider the two faces containing $uv$ and $uw$. In order for both to have length 3 or less, we would need two parallel edges from $v$ to $w$, but we're dealing with simple graphs. This is assuming our graph is not a triangle, which we can since $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Since nothing else happened, I accepted this answer. One thing that worries me is that the task says nothing about maximally planar graphs (and we never mentioned such a thing in our course) and I don't understand why maximal planarity proves this for any other planar graph, but okay.

Comment: @darxsys Consider any general planar graph. You could successively add edges to it to eventually make it maximally planar. Note that the degree of any vertex in the maximally planar graph is larger than the degree of the corresponding vertex in the original graph. So if the maximally planar graph has 4 vertices of degree at most 5, then the corresponding 4 vertices in the original graph would also have degree at most 5.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Comment: Please explain how 'Now suppose G has at most 3 vertices of degree 5 or less. Then 2m≥ 6(n−3)+3⋅3 = 6n−9' came to be. Thanks.

Comment: @Sudheer The first sentence sets up a proof by contradiction (we're assuming it's not true that there are at least 4 vertices of degree 5 or less). Then $2m$ is the sum of the degrees of all the vertices (Handshaking Lemma). There 3 vertices that have degree at least 3, and the remaining $n-3$ vertices have degree at least 6, so the sum of the degrees is at least $6(n-3) + 3 \cdot 3$, and we have $2m \geq 6(n-3) + 3 \cdot 3$.

Comment: Please clarify the symbol "δ(G)≥3." Does it denote the number of vertices of G? Or sum of degrees of vertices of G?

Comment: Now it occurs to me that, "δ(G)≥3." degree of every vertex of G >= 3. Still, would like to get confirmation.

Comment: @Sudheer $\delta(G)$ is the minimum of the degrees of all vertices in $G$. So $\delta(G) \geq 3$ means all vertices have degree at least 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assume to the contrary that no more than three vertices have degree 5 or less, so all but three have degree at least six. That mean $n \geq 6(m-3)+3 = 6m-15$ or $m \leq \frac{n+15}{6}$. But you have shown that $m \geq 3n$. Combining, we get $\frac{n+15}{6} \geq 3n$ or $17n \leq 15$, which is absurd.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the first line of the proof where you put the inequality n >= 6(m-3) + 3. Where does that come from?

Comment: $(m-3)$ vertices have degree at least 6, and the other 3 have degree at least 1. Now, calculate edges emanating from each vertice. Probably, $n \geq 3(m-3) + \frac{3}{2}$ would be better, as we might have calculated edges twice. That will lead to $28n \leq 15$, which is still absurd.

Comment: You have $n$ and $m$ reversed, and how do you know there aren't isolated vertices? You should have $2m \geq 6(n-3)$, but that doesn't contradict what is known.

Comment: Exactly @PerryIverson